# How to install powershell modules within a docker container off the mcr.microsoft.com/powershell image?

Tags: powershell, docker

Please, observe:

```
C:\> docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /> Get-PSRepository
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
PS /> Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
NuGet                    3.0.0.1          Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag, Contains, AllowPrereleaseVersions, ConfigFile, SkipVali…
PowerShellGet            2.1.3.0          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, InstallUpdate, NoPathUpdate, AllowPrereleaseVersions, Fil…

PS /> Register-PSRepository -Default
PS /> Get-PSRepository
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.
PS /> $env:PSModulePath
/root/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/opt/microsoft/powershell/6/Modules
PS />
```

So, there is no PS repositories. OK, I run `Register-PSRepository -Default` - it does not fail. But it also does nothing - I still have no PS repositories.

Other people have the same issue, but I did not understand how they resolved it. What blows my mind is that it is microsoft's powershell image that does not work.

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

Please, allow me to clarify the acceptance criteria for an answer. If your answer shows how one can run `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh` and then `Get-PSRepository` - you hit the mark and get the points.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I disconnect from my VPN, and I run `Register-PSRepository` it performs as expected. It is only on the VPN that it fails. I suspect the issue is that it has to reach.. Something (www.powershellgallery.com?) in order to successfully register the repository.

It looks like this after execution:

```Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

Comment: I did not have any issues in my environment, even being on VPN (although I'm not using Cisco AnyConnect as some having issues seem to be). Does name resolution work? You can test with `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('www.powershellgallery.com')`

Answer (score 3):

The answer for me seems to be to run this after I connect to VPN

```
Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 1
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

I found this at https://sysblog.dk/?p=254

If you would like to "set it and forget it", follow [these instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277#issuecomment-738839732) for setting up a scheduled task trigger.

Comment: I thought this was the fix, but now I am having the problem again. This is incredibly frustrating, but I think it still confirms that VPN is the issue.

Comment: I have additional security features that are getting in the way, but once I get around those, this is still a valid fix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the issue was that the container was connected to the internet but not were not finding the DNS address. If you run `ping google.com` and does not work you have a similar problem.

The fix is to set `"dns": ["1.1.1.1"]` in the Docker JSON configuration file as described here: [Not able to access internet inside docker windows container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766135/not-able-to-access-internet-inside-docker-windows-container)

Comment: The image I am talking about does not have ping.

Comment: I did this, but still get `The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.powershellgallery.com'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in Linux this is the point because:

```
$ docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell bash
root@a92d3c657304:/# apt -qq update; apt install -qq -y iputils-ping
root@a92d3c657304:/# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.215.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from zrh11s02-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.215.228): icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=6.01 ms
64 bytes from zrh11s02-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.215.228): icmp_seq=2 ttl=111 time=6.04 ms
64 bytes from zrh11s02-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.215.228): icmp_seq=3 ttl=111 time=5.49 ms
```

Comment: What question are you answering here?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was very simply: disconnect from the VPN, then run `Register-PSRepository -Default` inside the container.